# fragment NullPointException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I just wanted to get the value of the edit-text in the fragment and display it in textView by creating a String function and return the text->String and a another String function to return the value from the edittext in fragment and display it with Button Save(just for testing) in my MainActivity, But it keep giving me this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
 at com.example.Thisporject.fragment.fragment_fr_Person.TogetNameText(fragment_fr_Person.java:97)
at com.example.Thisporject.CreateGame.CreateGameGenerated.getNameEditText(CreateGameGenerated.java:60)
        at com.example.Thisporject.CreateGame.CreateGameGenerated.SaveAllContent(CreateGameGenerated.java:79)
```

FragmentActivity.Java:

```
public class fragment_fr_Person extends Fragment  {
    View rootView;
    EditText NameEdit;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_person, container, false);
        NameEdit = rootView.findViewById(R.id.Name_Editext);


       



        return rootView;
    }

    public String TogetNameText(){
        return NameEdit.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
 public class CreateGameGenerated extends FragmentActivity {
    Button Save_btn;
    ImageView displayImage;
    FloatingActionButton addPhotoFloating_btn;
    fragment_list frag;
    List<fragment_list> qqf = new ArrayList<>();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_game_generated);
        Save_btn = findViewById(R.id.Save_btn);
        displayImage = findViewById(R.id.display_ImageView);
        addPhotoFloating_btn = findViewById(R.id.photo_gallery_acess_btn);
        TextView testName = findViewById(R.id.testName);
        TextView testAge = findViewById(R.id.testAge);


        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.tags_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.tags, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        Save_btn.setOnClickListener(this::SaveAllContent);
    }


    public  String getNameEditText(){
        fragment_fr_Person fragment_fr_person;
        fragment_fr_person = new fragment_fr_Person();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
        fragmentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();

        return fragment_fr_person.TogetNameText();
    }

    public String getAgeEditText(){
        fragment_fr_Person fragment_fr_person;
        fragment_fr_person = new fragment_fr_Person();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
        fragmentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
        //Handler

        return fragment_fr_person.TogetAgeText();

    }

    private void SaveAllContent(View view) {
        TextView testName = findViewById(R.id.testName);
        TextView testAge = findViewById(R.id.testAge);

        testName.setText(getNameEditText());
        testAge.setText(getAgeEditText());

    }


}
```

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/EditTextMainContainer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageViewAndEdit"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ThisProject.fragment.fragment_fr_Person">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id = "@+id/NameContainer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:text="@string/TextName"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name_Editext"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/template"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewName"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:hint="@string/insert_here" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivy.xml

```
            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id ="@+id/fragment_generated_mainView"
                android:name="com.example.ThisProject.fragment.fragment_fr_Person"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tags_spinner"
                />
            <TextView android:id ="@+id/testName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageViewAndEdit"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNameEditText` this method looks wrong to me

you should get your fragment using `findFragmentById()` or save to a variable when you instantiate it. Then you can call your `mFragment.TogetNameText()` from your activity

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code to get value from EditText to onViewCreated. This will execute the code after the view is created. Also check if R.id.Name_Editext exists in the layout
R.layout.fragment_fr_person.

```
@Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
NameEdit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Name_Editext);
}
```

Comment: The ```R.id.NameEdit``` does exist  and I put it inside the onViewCreated, but nothing worked so far

Comment: Add the (EditText) cast before findViewById call.